# Feature (@javascript) testing doesn't work well

Tags: php, selenium, rhel, behat

I'm setting up a simple check when I type a keyword in an input field in browser to see the result.
And when the checking begins on the javascript part, the check is made long time to finish with error.

I'm using : Linux RedHat 7
            Behat 3.5.0
            Selenium Standalone Server 3.141.59
            Mink 1.6

```
# behat.yml

default: 
  extensions: 
    Behat\MinkExtension: 
      browser_name: chrome
      goutte: ~
      javascript_session: selenium2
      selenium2: 
        wd_host: http://99.80.48.204:4444/wd/hub
        capabilities: { "browser": "chrome", "version": "*", 'chrome': {'switches':['--start-maximized']}}
      base_url: https://www.bing.com
  suites: 
    ui: 
      contexts: [FeatureContext, WebContext]
```

```
#Webcontext.php

<?php

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class WebContext extends MinkContext {

     /**
     *@When I wait for :arg1 seconds
     */
    public function iWaitForSeconds($args)
    {
      $this->getSession()->wait($args * 1000);
    }

    /**
     * @When I fill in :arg1 with: :arg2
     */
    public function iFillInWith($value, $field)
    {
      $javascript = "window.onload = function () {var e = document.getElementById('$field').value='$value';}";
      $this->getSession()->executeScript($javascript);
    }

}
```

```
# bing.feature

@insulated
Feature: Bing

  Scenario: Homepage
    Given I am on the homepage
    Then  I should see "Bing"
    And I should see "Images"
    And I should see "Office Online"
  @javascript
  Scenario: Search
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I fill in "sb_form_q" with "grafikart" 
    And I wait for 1 seconds
    Then I should see "Grafikart.fr"
```

I expect a quick checking and all of my lines are green, but currently it doesn't work.

Comment: What error do you get? what command have you used to run?

Comment: I ran with **bin/behat** and when the check is in When I fill in "sb_form_q" with "grafikart"..... The error is : **Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "sb_form_q" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)**

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the page is not loaded yes and the element is not in the page.

Try to:
1. wait for the page to be loaded using wait method
`->wait(5000, "document.readyState === 'complete'");`

2. wait for the element to be present if needed using a loop in php or see if you can use the `wait` with a condition like `document.getElementById('$field') != null`

Depending on the case you might need just one of these or both if you are navigating from another page, the second one you can include it in the fill method.
After the wait is done you can fill the field.

+change your `$javascript` method to
`document.getElementById('$field').value='$value';`

Comment: Hi Lauda, I tried your method but the result is the same.
I changed my scenario to verify if it was maybe my **Feature** was failed but no.
The check is during more 8min to get a bad result

Comment: Thank you Laud for your editing, but I always the same problem. When I'm running my Behat. The scenario without the @javascript tag is done/green right away. At the moment the script is starting to check the second scenario, it make a time and error.
I check in all FAQ - Forum and others to find a solution but without success...

Answer (score 0):

finally I've been modifying my configuration of selenium and Behat. Now the link is working between both.

But when I'm launching my behat test ---> **bin/behat** 
The code is running faster than previously but I've still an error:

```
 Could not open connection: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browser: chrome, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 76.0.3809.12, ignoreZoomSetting: false, javascriptEnabled: true, name: Behat feature suite, platform: LINUX, selenium-version: 3.141.59} (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
```

I'm searching throught many FAQ to get a response but no chance.
Please does somebody can help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I finally managed to make the link between behat - selenium and my webdriver.
My last mistake is this:

> could not open connection: unknown error: cannot find ChromeBinary

[image]

However, when I launch the Behat command, the Chromedriver is working throught the processes.

Thank per advance